# DateField Vaadin Component with SQL Date

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, vaadin, sql-date-functions

So, I have a property SQL.Date in my POJO class. I want to bind it using Binder from Vaadin Component, but always returned like this:

```
Property type 'java.sql.Date' doesn't match the field type 'java.time.LocalDate'. Binding should be configured manually using converter.
```

So here's my Getter Setter contained in the POJO class

```
public Date getDateOfBirth() {
    return dateOfBirth;
}

public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) { this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth; }
```

And here's when I use the Binder component:

```
binder = new Binder<>(Person.class);
binder.bindInstanceFields( this );
```

FYI, I use Spring Boot JPA for the data. Is there any relation between the error message and usage of Spring Boot?

Comment: Which version? Vaadin8?

Comment: yeah, Vaadin 8.0.0

Comment: If you don't provide a full stacktrace it is hard to tell which lib is causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

> Property type 'java.sql.Date' doesn't match the field type
>   'java.time.LocalDate'. Binding should be configured manually using
>   converter.

tells what to do. Without seeing your code I assume you have Vaadin `DateField` in some Vaadin `FormLayout` that you are trying to populate with `java.sql.Date` value (or `binder.bindInstanceFields()` tries).

Unfortunately `DateField` seems to accept only `LocalDate`. Therefore you need to convert the value somehow.

There are lots of different "date" converters in vaadin `Converter` type hierarchy but this one is missing (or maybe I missed it?) so I created it:

```
public class SqlDateToLocalDateConverter
       implements Converter<LocalDate,java.sql.Date> {
    @Override
    public Result<java.sql.Date> convertToModel(LocalDate value,
           ValueContext context) {
        if (value == null) {
            return Result.ok(null);
        }
        return Result.ok( java.sql.Date.valueOf( value) );
    }
    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToPresentation(java.sql.Date value,
           ValueContext context) {
        return value.toLocalDate();
    }
}
```

It seems that you are using declarative ui? I am no able to tell it now howto port this with that with little effort.

If you were binding fields manually it would go like this:

```
    binder.forField(myForm.getMyDateField())
       .withConverter(new SqlDateToLocalDateConverter())
       .bind(MyBean::getSqlDate, MyBean::setSqlDate);
```

So i guess you need to find a way to add this converter to handle assumed `DateField`. Anyway message suggests that you might not be able to use the easy way `binder.bindInstanceFields()` but bind fields manually.

Comment: ahhh okay. thanks for the explanation and also thanks for the Source Code of the Converter. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom date field and use it instead of DateField. Then you don't need to bind it every time just use automated binding

```
public class CustomDateField extends CustomField<Date> {
    DateField dateField;

    public CustomDateField(String caption) {
        setCaption(caption);
        dateField = new DateField();
        dateField.setDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
    }

    @Override
    protected Component initContent() {
        return dateField;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doSetValue(Date date) {
        dateField.setValue(date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate());
    }

    @Override
    public Date getValue() {
        return dateField.getValue() != null ? Date.from(dateField.getValue().atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()) : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: woow. I just realized that we can create a custom class in Vaadin. Thank you for the answer.